# "/root" directory is missing in Yocto build

Tags: linux, kernel, yocto

I have a [yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/) based Linux build system. I see the "/root" directory is missing. I have the other usual directories under "/". Does anyone know who creates "root" directory under "/" ?

P.S. I'm using [squashFS](http://squashfs.sourceforge.net/) as the root file system, so I boot to a temporary [initramfs](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/initramfs.html) and later do a switch_root to the final root file system (squashFS).

Comment: Whether `/root` exists depends on the OS. IBM AIX systems don’t have `/root`, for example.

Comment: `/root` is usually root's home directory. Check your `/etc/passwd` or equivalent to see where `root`'s home directory is.

Answer (score 0):

By default, root home is in `/home/root` in Yocto, and you need to set [ROOT_HOME](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-ROOT_HOME) variable to set it to `/root`

***local.conf:***

`ROOT_HOME = "/root"`